# NSLocale NSLocale preferredLanguages is not updating on language change

Tags: ios, localization

I am trying to get the current preferred language selected by the user using the following piece of code:

```
NSString *language = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];
```

This is giving me the preferred language as expected for the first time the app is run but **the changes are not reflected once I change the language in the system settings.** If I uninstall the app, then change the language and then again reinstall the app, the app is now working for this new language (and is only showing this language)

Here's what is happening:

> - The language is set to English (Australian) when the app is first installed.
> - The app will show `*language` gives the value `en-AU` (correct value).
> - Now the language is now changed to Serbian.
> - After restarting the app `*language` is still giving `en-AU` whereas it should have `sr-XX`.
> - After re-installing the app, the `language` is showing the correct value `sr-XX` and the app is working as expected but now it won't change to any other language (as described)

I am testing the app directly on an iPhone (iOS 11). I have added the localization resources in the project settings and just to be sure I have also set the default application language as *System Preferred* in scheme.

I also tried to use `currentLocale` but it is still giving the same result.

I also found the following code somewhere, this also is giving and array 2 elements but is behaving the same as `preferredLanguage` and not changing with the language change.

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSMutableArray *languages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[userDefaults objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"]];
```

I am relatively new to iOS dev and not sure where I'm doing it wrong. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to locale that "always reflects the latest configuration settings", use [`autoupdatingCurrent`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nslocale/1414388-autoupdatingcurrent) in Swift, [`autoupdatingCurrentLocale`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nslocale/1414388-autoupdatingcurrentlocale?language=objc) in Objective-C.

You might also want to establish yourself as an observer of [`NSLocale.currentLocaleDidChangeNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nslocale/1418141-currentlocaledidchangenotificati) in Swift, [`NSCurrentLocaleDidChangeNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscurrentlocaledidchangenotification?language=occ) in Objective-C, if you want to be notified of any changes if the app happens to be suspending or running in background when the locale changes (in order to, for example, update the UI accordingly).

Comment: Thank you so much.